# How to count the number of possible solutions for a sudoku board using backtracking

Tags: ocaml

This is a followup of:
[Need some feedback on my fold_neighbours attempt on this problem in Ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69044124/need-some-feedback-on-my-fold-neighbours-attempt-on-this-problem-in-ocaml)

I got some really good advices and applied them when i implemented this version.

This is what i have right now, the program can actually read a sudoku and solve it. Here is a demo:

```
Input board 
530070000
600195000
098000060
800060003
400803001
700020006
060000280
000419005
000080079

Solved board 
534678912
672195348
198342567
859761423
426853791
713924856
961537284
287419635
345286179

Input board 
480006902
002008001
900370060
840010200
003704100
001060049
020085007
700900600
609200018

Solved board 
487156932
362498751
915372864
846519273
593724186
271863549
124685397
738941625
659237418
```

This is the code at the moment

```
type vertex = int * int 

type gamma = int


module V = Map.Make(struct
    type t = vertex
    let compare = Stdlib.compare
  end)

module G = Set.Make(struct
    type t = gamma 
    let compare = compare end)

type pc = gamma V.t

(* Help methods for coloring *)

let color v pc = V.find v pc
let color_vertex v c pc = V.update v (fun _ -> Some c) pc
let is_uncolored v pc = color v pc = 0

let allcolors = (let acc = ref G.empty
                 in
                 for gamma = 1 to 9 do
                   acc := G.add gamma (!acc)
                 done;
                 !acc
                )

(* Reads a textfile representing sudoku *)
let ascii_digit c = Char.code c - Char.code '0'

let read_matrix_from_channel chan =
  let rec loop i j grid =
    match input_char chan with
    | exception End_of_file -> grid
    | '\n' -> loop (i+1) 0 grid
    | '0'..'9' as c ->
      loop i (j+1) @@
      V.add (i,j) (ascii_digit c) grid
    | _ -> invalid_arg "invalid input" in
  loop 0 0 V.empty

let matrix_from_file file =
  let chan = open_in file in
  let r = read_matrix_from_channel chan in
  close_in chan;
  r

(* Prints a pretty sudokuboard (not used in the demo) *)
let print_board vertex = 
  let print_node (_x,_y) _grid =
    if _y = 0
    then Printf.printf "\n | ";
    print_int _grid;
    print_string " | "
  in 
  V.iter print_node vertex


(*executes a function on all vertices *)
let fold_vertices f acc =
  let acc' = ref acc in
  for i=0 to 8 do
    for j=0 to 8 do
      acc' := f (i,j) (!acc')
    done
  done;
  !acc'


let find_vertex pred =
  fold_vertices
    (fun v a -> match a with
       | None -> if pred v then Some v else None
       | _ -> a) None

(* neighbours *)
let is_neighbour (i,j) (i',j') =
  if (i,j) = (i',j') then
    false
  else if i = i' || j = j' then
    true
  else
    (i/3) = (i'/3) && (j/3) = (j'/3)

(* fold_neighbours  *)
let fold_neighbours f v acc =
  let ff u acc =
    if is_neighbour u v then f u acc else acc
  in fold_vertices ff acc            

(* Checks if vertex is allowed *)
let allowed v pc =
  fold_neighbours (fun u allowed ->
      match color u pc with
      | 0 -> allowed
      | c -> G.remove c allowed)
    v allcolors


(* Solve *)
let rec solve pc =
  match find_vertex (fun v -> is_uncolored v pc) with
  | Some v ->
    let all = allowed v pc in
    G.fold (fun c -> function
        | None -> color_vertex v c pc |> solve
        | opc -> opc)
      all None
  | None -> Some pc
```

Ive got a problem now, not sure how to this. I want to count all the possible solutions for a sudoku using backtracking. So i want to just return the number of solutions as a integer.

I think i somehow need to recursively call the solve method in a "nsolve" method. Return None if there are no solution, else i check that the solution isnt the same as earlier, if its not i return Some solution and counts up else i return None.

Otherwise,maybe there is some way to get the approximate number of solutions. Because i guess that for an almost empty sudoku board it will take a very long time to recursively get the number of solutions. An empty sudoku board have 10^21 solutions, which is a lot. I don't know how to tackle this issue.
I there another way of doing this?

This is the method im trying to implement([nsolve pc]):

```
(** [nsolve pc] uses backtracking to count the number of possible solution to the sudoku. *)
let rec nsolve pc = .....
```

Comment: This seems like more of a domain problem than a programming problem, and as such is off-topic on SO. Perhaps it's a better fit in [math.se]

Comment: Possibly worth noting that counting the solutions to a _well-formed_ sudoku is easy. There's only one.

Comment: Chris - true but i dont think we should ignore the "less" well-formed ones

Comment: This is not a mathematical problem. Mathematics already answered (maybe not definitive, see http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/sudoku/felgenhauer_jarvis_spec1.pdf) it, and said that in the end they have to brute-force. So the OP question is how to brute-force the number of solutions using backtracking.

Comment: you already have a bactracking solver, the only problem with it is that it returns the same answer for the same board. You need somehow to force it returning a different answer. I see two approaches: (1) you can permute your colors set (right now you assign colors in the same order every time), or (2) you can constrain your solver to prevent it from choosing an already taken solution.

Comment: Yeah im currently trying to implement option (2) but i cant get the conditionals to work properly. :/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is by brute-forcing it. In pseudo code this would be

```
fun nb_sol cpt i j grid = 
  if i > 8 /\ j > 8 then cpt + 1
  else if is_empty grid(i)(j) then 
    for k = 1 to 9 do 
      grid(i)(j) <- k
      if is_ok grid then
        res += (if j > 8 then nb_sol cpt (i+1) 0 grid
          else nb_sol cpt i (j+1) grid)
    done
    grid(i)(j) <- empty
```

I didn't check if it was exactly what you wanted but you got the idea :-)